# Best way to insert 10,000 JSON files (total 30GB) into MongoDB

Tags: python, json, node.js, mongodb

It doesn't look to me that using python to combine all the json files is convenient, and the combined file would be 30G.

I am using mongoDB and nodejs. The way how I populate a sample json is:

```
var data = require('./data1.json')
var populateDB = function() {
   db.collection('temp', function(err, collection) {
    collection.insert(data, {safe:true}, function(err, result) {});
 });
};
```

This only adds one json file. How should I populate the collection with the 10000+ json files from here? any suggestion is highly appreciated!

Comment: are all the files called `./dataXXXX.json` ? as in do they have preceding zeros

Comment: nah, the actual files have all have some random numbers

Answer (score 1, accepted):

The easiest way would be to write a Node program that processes one JSON file and then run it multiple time from the shell:

```
for i in *.json; do node program.js $i; done
```

Your Node program would just need to access the name from `process.argv` instead of having it hardcoded but the logic would be the same.

If you want to do everything in node then you will have to read the directory, get all `.json` files, read every one of them in sequence and then run a code similar to the one you posted. If it's a one off task then you can even get away with using the "Sync" functions to simplify your code if it's a sequential task to do one thing at a time and you don't care about adding the data in parallel.

Comment: do you think it would a good idea to use bash to combine all the json? would that eat up all the RAM?

Comment: @user3669481 I don't think it would be a good idea to use bash to combine all json file. I think it would be a good idea to use bash to run your node program that can handle processing one json file.

Comment: I ended up using bash without node to insert all the data, but your answer is extremely helpful!

Answer (score 0):

Something like this would work

`npm i glob-fs mongodb async --save`

```
const async = require('async');
const fs = require('fs');
const glob = require('glob-fs')({ gitignore: true });
const MongoClient = require('mongodb').MongoClient;

const files = './files/data*.json';
const collection = 'test';
const url = 'mongodb://localhost:27017/test';

// Connect to db
MongoClient.connect(url, function (err, db) {
  if (err) {
    console.log(err);
  }

  // Get the collection
  const col = db.collection(collection);

  glob.readdirPromise(files)
    .then(function (f) {
      return async.eachSeries(f, (item, callback) => {

        fs.readFile(item, 'utf8', function (err, data) {
          if (err) {
            return console.log(err);
          }

          // Insert into mongo
          col.insertMany(JSON.parse(data)).then((r) => {
            console.log(r);
            return callback(r);
          }).catch(function (fail) {
            console.log(fail)
          });

        });
      }, err => {
        console.log(err);
      });
    })
    .then(err => {
      if (err) {
        db.close();
      }
    })
    .catch(err => {
      console.log(err);
    });
});
```

Comment: what do the json files look like? are they a result of `mongoexport`? https://docs.mongodb.com/manual/reference/program/mongoexport/